# How do I convert an encrypted RSA message cipher output into a matrix table?

Tags: matrix, number-theory, cryptography

```
     RSAcrack[cipher, n, e]
        
        ClearAll["`*"]
        
        p = 12131072439211271897323671531612440428472427633701410925634549312301964373042085619324197365322416866541017057361365214171711713797974299334871062829803541; 
        
        q = 12027524255478748885956220793734512128733387803682075433653899983955179850988797899869146900809131611153346817050832096022160146366346391812470987105415233; 
        
        n = p*q;
        
        e = 65537; 
        
        [Phi] = (p - 1)*(q - 1);
        
        d = PowerMod[e, -1, [Phi]];
        
        message1 = 
          "Simplicity is a great virtue but it requires hard work to achieve it and education to appreciate it. And to make matters worse: complexity sells better. Edsger Dijkstra"; 
        
        c = ascii = ToCharacterCode[message1]
        
        c = Row[DeleteCases[
           First[Row[{83, 105, 109, 112, 108, 105, 99, 105, 116, 121, 32, 105, 115, 
              32, 97, 32, 103, 114, 101, 97, 116, 32, 118, 105, 114, 116, 117, 101, 
              32, 98, 117, 116, 32, 105, 116, 32, 114, 101, 113, 117, 105, 114, 101, 
              115, 32, 104, 97, 114, 100, 32, 119, 111, 114, 107, 32, 116, 111, 32, 
              97, 99, 104, 105, 101, 118, 101, 32, 105, 116, 32, 97, 110, 100, 32, 
              101, 100, 117, 99, 97, 116, 105, 111, 110, 32, 116, 111, 32, 97, 112, 
              112, 114, 101, 99, 105, 97, 116, 101, 32, 105, 116, 46, 32, 65, 110, 
              100, 32, 116, 111, 32, 109, 97, 107, 101, 32, 109, 97, 116, 116, 101, 
              114, 115, 32, 119, 111, 114, 115, 101, 58, 32, 99, 111, 109, 112, 108, 
              101, 120, 105, 116, 121, 32, 115, 101, 108, 108, 115, 32, 98, 101, 116, 
              116, 101, 114, 46, 32, 69, 100, 115, 103, 101, 114, 32, 68, 105, 106, 
              107, 115, 116, 114, 97}]], ","]]
c^e mod n
```

This is what i have so far. I get the ascii numbers from the output of the last line in the code. But i want them in a matrix table so that I can send it away for someone to try an decrypt it. How do I do this?

Comment: Why are you using Row? This is for presentation purposes and should not be involved in computations. Your code is messy and missing details - you have mistakes too: `[Phi]` which should be `\[Phi]`, and `c^e mod n` at the end which is not Mathematica syntax. Could you please clarify what you mean by _matrix table_. If you want your output in a grid, maybe you should provide a nested list to `Grid`. Also your `DeleteCases` is wrong - you're deleting the string ",".

Answer (score 1):

`toNumbers` here is the inverse of `toText`. I've written the output to a text file - one number per line. It's up to you how big you want to make the chunks - I've chosen 32 bytes.

```
message1 = "Simplicity is a great virtue but it requires hard work to achieve it and education to appreciate it. And to make matters worse: complexity sells better. Edsger Dijkstra";

p = 12131072439211271897323671531612440428472427633701410925634549312301964373042085619324197365322416866541017057361365214171711713797974299334871062829803541;
q = 12027524255478748885956220793734512128733387803682075433653899983955179850988797899869146900809131611153346817050832096022160146366346391812470987105415233;
n = p*q;
e = 65537;

toText[numbers_] := StringJoin[
   FromCharacterCode[Reverse[IntegerDigits[#, 256]]] & /@ numbers];

toNumbers[text_, chunksize_] := 
 FromDigits[Reverse[#], 256] & /@ 
  Partition[ToCharacterCode@text, chunksize, chunksize, 1, 0]

ciphertext = PowerMod[toNumbers[message1, 32], e, n];
Export["ciphertext.txt", ciphertext]
```

```
37246423807947804842303396620313731332121100158526755958591270381921821200458849438334437481325903271103670394003399485924896799836133289482148132495808352652521492077384268056065417706138911806850949604339919310879586464998455667688887884799103770164760299295591292811032262366452580494949621860046894120030
70625283227481498188191129068432470280389507710975765530625636306629406992249893658081346464754951288622031801261462708714942932463422405804249043642616400465108126650506716369126389321179430134194630983661284444641219318650438600976259008086169010383063245958663150467019394143347513421913514262795956900326
69193040614674370771279136586290811484959747212510764149474224457457117760633019819590383820089391127672214757945673658671942041928148037773805198082904847727592965786606295052310814318074907746263161921038887882458662053556170921518587922089350195877645575370737266204943511031597320490738114282866598686146
139659124044241300833008452280274773364472223961785761319098615162095354806546897092844698150020302950189327150084814454507977090281110771089154927255330443365883973102772154939594044347426180486440481093611659652606342321810555350178453257265958614016184673151673943824136839351382663543448590193217691590170
45084933859438049317995247663370346600069031101678449928741859562991158083652666484771875097020895838496359490065446688642591554649883000884126912601223864961407212286873848399558621079663086487894619964782044024441923197202556949461758009411580167812314933637885252956724014641896027174625863187653559519578
61947261742093059553288143490615730151334985968370112798904868618984604055014947478543528097768012312325575412564953725928693527265984268519403312565204692522991752661230021085702257900016523807934240195970554536689610698706268509180351060600262169696545183009729489331843274002372097874647155885408677408433
```